# Android Navigation Drawer item icon

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I downloaded the sample app for the *Navigation Drawer* from

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Now I'd like to add an icon to a specific item in the list; for example

- Logout_icon + "Logout"

How can I do this? (Code please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are implementing the `Navigation Drawer` by a `ListView`, you will need to modify the layout for the list item by adding an ImageView. Then you should modify the adapter you use to populate the `ListView` so that it sets the `src` of the `ImageView` accordingly.

Quoting the guide you linked:

```
 // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
```

That's where most of your changes will be wired: specifying a layout containing a TextView and and ImageView and creating a new Adapter.

As a convenience, you might create a class called something like NavDrawerItem which will have two fields: one for the icon, the other the caption which you'll display through a `TextView`.

In your adapter, be sure to consider the menu items for which you won't be displaying an icon.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
            mdrawerlayout,
            R.drawable.ic_whats_hot,
            R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name)
    {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
        {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        public void onDrawerOpened(View view)
        {
            getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    {
        return true;
    }
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_settings:

            intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivitySetting.class);

            startActivity(intent1);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_websearch:

            intent1=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://http://www.vogella.com/"));
            startActivity(intent1);
            return true;

        default :

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

try this in coding and in  XML file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_websearch"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
    android:title="search"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="Settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

    >
</item>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:title="logout"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

    />
```